# Creating Node JS Cluster having issue in login

Tags: node.js, express, nodes, passport.js

I created cluster for my NodeJs application

```js
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
 var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;

 console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');

 for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
  cluster.fork();
 }

 cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
  console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
 });

 cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
  console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code
    + ', and signal: ' + signal);
  console.log('Starting a new worker');
  cluster.fork();
 });
} else {
 require('./server');
}
```

here I think clustering has started 4 to 5 processes 
but when I login in my app it is again redirecting to login page.
I am using passport npm for login

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve in else part ? you have just required the server module .
Can u post server.js code ?

Answer (score 1):

When using sessions, make sure you store your sessions inside a db and not in memory since each request will be redirected to a different cluster, hence you will lose the session.

Use something like connect-mongo for your sessions(if using mongodb)
https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo

Comment: I am using passport npm so , is there any solution related to passport